# Globally importing ReactJS components in all files

Tags: javascript, node.js

In React when you wanna import components from other files we use:

```js
import ComponentName from 'somePlace';
```

That works fine, but I wanna know if there is a way to import the content of a file instead of the exports. I wanna put all import statements for components in a single file (e.g. `imports.js`) and have a statement like:

```js
import './import.js' to all documents;
```

so all my components are automatically imported everywhere.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globally import modules? Not really, no. And neither should you need to.

A hacky "solution" would be assigning all imports to the global context (e.g. `window` in the browser) so it's accessible that way. That's possible, but definitely not recommended. It'll also prevent your bundler (most likely Webpack) from optimizing a lot of code.

Apart from the technical aspect, there are other reasons not to do so. If you specify the imports in each file, you know exactly what imports that file needs and under what variables it is imported as for that file.

---

If you still want to simplify importing the same components over and over again, you can have this setup:

**imports.js**

```js
// For default exports
import ComponentA from 'wherever';
export { ComponentA };

// For regular exports
//import { ComponentB } from 'wherever';
export { ComponentB } from 'wherever';

// For whole modules
//import * as wherever from 'wherever';
export * as wherever from 'wherever';
```

**someOtherFile.js**

```js
// Either import as a namespace
import * as Imports from './imports';
console.log([
    Imports.ComponentA,
    Imports.ComponentB,
    Imports.wherever.someFieldFromTheWhereverModule,
]);

// Or partial import
import { ComponentA, ComponentB } from './imports';
```

Comment: so you are suggesting to import each and every file/component individually ?? instead of importing all components in one file and then importing that new file to all other files ???

Comment: @AbdulMuhamin Yes. That's how everyone does it, that's how it's meant to be done. Years ago it was quite normal, especially in the browser, to polute the global context. You'd inject jQuery's `$` and other globals, sometimes overriding each other, while also making it unclear where globals came from. I'll edit my answer to give you a way of combining components into a single file to make it a bit easier to import.

Comment: Thx, i'll follow your suggestion.

Comment: @AbdulMuhamin I edited my answer with an example of a setup that you might like. If this answer is the most helpful (might change later if someone else answers), mark this answer as the solution.